# Add the other values of a dictionary if certain keys are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my input. I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'name1':'a', 'name2':'b','val1':10,'val2':20},
 {'name1':'a', 'name2':'b','val1':15,'val2':25},
 {'name1':'r', 'name2':'s','val1':30,'val2':20}]
```

If the keys `name1` and `name2` have both the same value, then add `val1` and `val2`.

Here is the expected output:

```
[{'name1':'a', 'name2':'b','val1':25,'val2':45},
 {'name1':'r', 'name2':'s','val1':30,'val2':20}]
```

In the first dict and second dict, both `name1` is `a` and both `name2` is `b`, so we add their values.

I was trying with loop but was not getting anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please update it with example input and expected output.

Comment: Please show the code that you tried to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> dicts = [{'name1':'a', 'name2':'b','val1':10,'val2':20},
 {'name1':'a', 'name2':'b','val1':15,'val2':25},
 {'name1':'r', 'name2':'s','val1':30,'val2':20}] 
>>> new_dicts = []
>>> for k, groups in groupby(dicts, lambda d: (d.pop('name1'), d.pop('name2'))):
        new_d = {
             'name1': k[0], 
             'name2': k[1], 
             **sum([Counter(g) for g in groups], Counter())
            }
        new_dicts.append(new_d)

>>> new_dicts
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 25, 'val2': 45},
 {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]
```

On the other hand, if you use `pandas`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(dicts).groupby(['name1', 'name2']).sum().reset_index().to_dict('r')
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 25, 'val2': 45},
 {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]
```

If you want to do this without modules, you can try:

```
>>> new_dicts = []
>>> for d in dicts:
        if not new_dicts:
            new_dicts.append(d)
        else:
            last_dict = new_dicts[-1]
            if (last_dict['name1'], last_dict['name2']) == (d['name1'], d['name2']):
                last_dict['val1'] += d['val1']
                last_dict['val2'] += d['val2']
            else:
                new_dicts.append(d)
>>> new_dicts
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 25, 'val2': 45},
 {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]
```

**NOTE**:

First and third solution assume that your list is sorted, i.e. same `name1` `name2` entries will appear consecutively, if that is not the case, you can add this line at the beginning:

```
>>> dicts = sorted(dicts, key=lambda x: (x['name1'], x['name2']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate and use an intermediate dictionary where `(name1, name2)` is the key to achieve linear time time complexity.

```
>>> for d in l:
...     name1, name2, val1, val2 = d['name1'], d['name2'], d['val1'], d['val2']
...     if (name1, name2) in res:
...             res[(name1, name2)] = res[(name1, name2)][0] + val1, res[(name1, name2)][1] + val2
...     else:
...             res[(name1, name2)] = (val1, val2)
... 
>>> res
{('a', 'b'): (25, 45), ('r', 's'): (30, 20)}
>>> output = [{'name1': k[0], 'name2': k[1], 'val1': v[0], 'val2': v[1]} for k,v in res.items()]
>>> output
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 25, 'val2': 45}, {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Run it through pandas, which is keenly good at this type of stuff.  (and yes, this
could probably be collapsed down to 1 or 2 chained statements.:

```
In [37]: a                                                                                    
Out[37]: 
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 10, 'val2': 20},
 {'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 15, 'val2': 25},
 {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]

In [38]: df =  pd.DataFrame(a)                                                                

In [39]: df                                                                                   
Out[39]: 
  name1 name2  val1  val2
0     a     b    10    20
1     a     b    15    25
2     r     s    30    20

In [40]: grouped_sum = df.groupby(['name1', 'name2']).sum()                                   

In [41]: grouped_sum                                                                          
Out[41]: 
             val1  val2
name1 name2            
a     b        25    45
r     s        30    20

In [42]: grouped_sum.reset_index(inplace=True)                                                

In [43]: data = grouped_sum.to_dict('records')                                                

In [44]: data                                                                                 
Out[44]: 
[{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 25, 'val2': 45},
 {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to post the code you tried and then ask for help, so others can help by suggesting some changes.
But something like this can help you,

```
di = [{'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'a', 'val1': 10, 'val2': 20},
      {'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'b', 'val1': 15, 'val2': 25},
      {'name1': 'r', 'name2': 's', 'val1': 30, 'val2': 20}]

for i in di:
    if i['name1'] == i['name2']:
        print("sum:", i['val1']+i['val2'])
```

It prints the sum of val1 and val2 if name1 amd name2 are equal.